# google sheets importxml not returning class name

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

In my spreadsheet I wanted to keep track of how many teams crossed the auto line from this [website](https://www.thebluealliance.com/match/2018nysu_qm1). If I use: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.thebluealliance.com/match/2018nysu_qm1","//table[2]//tr[1]/td[3]/span")`.
It won't work since there isn't anything in the `<span>` tag:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="red" colspan="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
  <td>Robot 1 Auto Run</td>
  <td class="blue" colspan="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
</tr>
```

So instead I wanted it to return the class name of the element by using this: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.thebluealliance.com/match/2018nysu_qm1","//table[2]//tr[1]/td[3]/span/@class")`. But it doesn't return anything. I tried to use it in on an on an [online tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) and it returned the classes I was looking for [here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPEYr.jpg). I am just wondering how come it does not work on google sheets, is there anyway to return the names of the classes?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind IMPORTHTML instead?:

```
=index(IMPORTHTML("https://www.thebluealliance.com/match/2018nysu_qm1","table"),0,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you expected to extract, so I will just create a simple example.

If the html is

```
<div class="card-request__itinerary">
            <span class="card-request__itinerary-label">Itinerario: </span>
            <span class="card-request__itinerary-content is-croped">
                Salida desde el puerto de Barcelona, visitando Palma, La Valletta (Malta), La Valletta (Malta), Heraklión (Creta), Haifa (Israel), Canal de Suez, Canal de Suez, Salalah (Omán), Muscat (Omán), Abu Dhabi (EAU) , 
            </span>
</div>
```

I get to extract the long description of the itinerary with

```
=IMPORTXML("url";"//span[@class='card-request__itinerary-content is-croped']")
```

Don't forget the `''` and note that if you right click on the element (from Webdev Tools) and click on 'copy path' or 'copy xpath' the path comes out as

`span.card-request__itinerary-content.is-croped`

which needs to be transformed to

`//span[@class='card-request__itinerary-content is-croped']`

It took me a while to figure it out, but here it is.

Note: Be aware, that the website you are crawling may have 'anti-bots' protection and queries may fail for reasons that have nothing to do with your query, like too many requests on the same url or too many requests from google sheets in a period of time.